# HTML часы идут неравномерно

Tags: javascript, html

У меня на странице есть следующие часы:

```js
function change_time(field){
    field.textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}

let date_time_field = document.querySelector('.preview_date_time')
setInterval(change_time, 500, date_time_field)
```

```html
<div class="preview_date_time"></div>
```

Они обновляются каждые 500 миллисекунд. Когда время в системных часах кратно 500 миллисекундам, секунды на странице могут сменяться неравномерно. Например, секунда может смениться чаще, чем раз в 1000 миллисекунд. Понаблюдайте за таймером секунд 20 и вы поймёте о чём я говорю.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу избавиться от дёрганья времени на странице?

Comment: Простой вариант — поставить интервал поменьше.

Comment: не заметил неравномерности в чем она выражается?

Comment: И вправду, практически мгновенно меняется 2 секунды.

Comment: Я думаю, что имеет место накопительный эффект.

Выполнение change_time занимает какое-то время. Из-за чего визуально это выглядит как "неравномерная" задержка между перерисовками. Под "неравномерностью" я имею ввиду корреляцию между реальным временем и частотой обновления !== 1000 мс. 

При этом разное время для воспроизведения кейса возникает из-за конкретного момента, т.к. setInterval практически никогда не устанавливается в момент Date.now() c 0 миллисекунд

Comment: Неравномерность наблюдается, когда секунду надо поменять через 10 мс, а таймер не поменяет её ещё 500 мс, потому что он только что поменял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно решить задачу с минимальной тратой процессора, если отказаться от `setInterval` в пользу `setTimeout`.

Миллисекунды из текущей даты вычитаем из тысячи - это время до начала следующей секунды. Добавляем к нему десять миллисекунд. Это время в начале следующей секунды, где нас и вызовет `setTimeout`. Это способ гарантирует от попадания на границу секунды. Получается настолько равномерный таймер, насколько это может обеспечить `setTimeout`. На незагруженной странице ошибки будут в районе одной миллисекунды. Код выполняется раз в секунду, так редко как это минимально необходимо:

```js
const field = document.querySelector('.preview_date_time');
const next_tick = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    field.textContent = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    setTimeout(next_tick, 10 + 1000 - date.getMilliseconds());
};
next_tick();
```

```html
<div class="preview_date_time"></div>
```

**P.S.** По стандарту можно было бы не прибавлять десять миллисекунд к началу следующей секунды. Задержка должна быть не меньше заданной - раньше начала секунды вызова быть не может. Но я не уверен что браузеры строго следуют стандарту, поэтому лучше прибавить.

Comment: Спасибо, я отметил это как ответ. Скажите пожалуйста, не приводит ли рекурсивный вызов `next_tick` к утечке памяти с течением времени в JS?

Comment: Нет, не приводит. Сборщик мусора собирает отработавшие вызовы `setTimeout`. В процессе ожидания в памяти один объект `setTimeout`. В момент срабатывания два - старый и новый.

Comment: В этом коде нет рекурсии. Следующий вызов `next_tick` кладётся в очередь ожидания. Когда его вызывают в стеке уже нет текущего вызова. В этом можно убедиться добавив отладочную печать в начало и конец `next_tick`.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, такое происходит из-за того что на самом деле интервал не ровный, часто бывает что интервал опаздывает на пару (или больше) миллисекунд. Можно в этом убедиться:

```js
function checkTime() {
  const now = Date.now()

  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const timePassed = Date.now() - now

      res(timePassed)
    }, 500)
  })
}

checkTime().then(time => {
  console.log('Прошло ' + time + ' миллисекунд')
})
```

Можно сделать вот так:

```js
function change_time(field) {
  field.textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}

let date_time_field = document.querySelector('.preview_date_time')

requestAnimationFrame(function onUpdate() {
  change_time(date_time_field)

  requestAnimationFrame(onUpdate)
})
```

```html
<div class="preview_date_time"></div>
```

**Но насчёт производительности ничего не обещаю.** Всё таки обновлять элемент, с той же частотой, как и обновляется монитор, дело такое.

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо найти более производительное решение. Я так понял, у часов в JS нет колбэка?
Может быть есть какая-нибудь другая функция, которая зависит от часов?

Comment: @NNL993 Согласен с вами, для большей наглядности можно использовать [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

Comment: @Aycon нет, такой функции / метода нигде нет (вроде бы).